# can't access string from a cell in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

**info:**

> C{1}(1)

```
 ans = 

'0.00000000     188000.00000000     '
```

> class(C{1}(1))

```
ans =

cell
```

**problem** (when I am trying to access the first number in the form of string, it refuse to give me):

> C{1}(1)(1:10)
>
> Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.

How may I get the first 10 string? Thanks

Comment: Try C{1}{1}(1:10)

Comment: worked. Thanks! Have been stupid lol